# Kendo grid save doesn't trigger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

(ASP .NET MVC)

I have a Kendo UI grid where everything works fine except the grid save button doesn't trigger. Edit and Cancel works properly, but when I click the save button nothing happens, not even the log method.

Here is the code:

```
@(Html.MaskableGrid<MunkatarsLog>("gridMunkatarsLog")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Command(commands =>
                                    {
                                        commands.Edit().Text("<span></span>").UpdateText("<span></span>").CancelText("<span></span>").HtmlAttributes(KendoHelper.EditHtmlAttributesFor(Model));
                                    }).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH_NARROWER).HeaderTemplate("<span class='k-icon k-i-warning'>").Visible(Model.CanUpdate || Model.CanDelete);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.MunkatarsLogId).Hidden(true);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.MunkatarsId).Hidden(true);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.Datum).Format("{0:yyyy.MM.dd.}").EditorTemplateName("Date");
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.MunkatarsEsemenyTipus.Nev).ClientTemplate("#=munkatarsLogClientTemplateBuilder(data)#").EditorTemplateName("MunkatarsEsemenyTipus").EditorViewData(new { Kod = "#=MunkatarsEsemenyTipus.Kod#", Nev = "#=MunkatarsEsemenyTipus.Nev#" });
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.EsemenyLeiras);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.BejegyzoMunkatarsId).Hidden(true);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.BejegyzesIdeje).Hidden(true);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.UtolsoModositoId).Hidden(true);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.UtolsoModositasIdeje).Hidden(true);
                                    columns.Bound(c => c.Version).Hidden(true);

                                })
                                .ToolBar(KendoHelper.GridToolbarFor<MunkatarsLog>(Model, false))
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 270px;" })
                                .Scrollable()
                                .Sortable()
                                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                                    .Refresh(true)
                                    .PageSizes(true)
                                    .ButtonCount(5))
                                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).DisplayDeleteConfirmation(StringResource.DeleteConfirm).Enabled(true))
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Model(m => m.Id(i => i.MunkatarsId))
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetAllMunkatarsLogForMunkatars", "MunkatarsLog").Data("selectedMunkatars"))
                                    .Create("AddNew", "MunkatarsLog")
                                    .Update("UpdateLog", "MunkatarsLog")
                                    .PageSize(20)
                                )
                                .Events(ev =>
                                {
                                    ev.DataBound("logGridBound");
                                    ev.Edit("logGridOnEdit");
                                    ev.Cancel("logGridOnCancel");
                                    ev.Save("logGridOnSave");

                                })
```

And the javascript functions:

```
function logGridOnEdit(e) {
    console.log("Edit");
}

function logGridOnSave(e) {
    console.log("Save");
}

function logGridOnCancel(e) {
    console.log("Cancel");
}
```

Only the Save doesn't trigger.

Comment: any errors or warnings in your console?

Comment: Nothing. That would be much easier. :/

Comment: I wonder if the <span> on your UpdateText is causing an issue? Does the rendered button have the k-grid-edit class on it?

Comment: It has "k-grid-update" on it. There are icons in there. It looks like this:

class="k-button k-button-icontext k-primary k-grid-update"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the follownig:

There were 3 columns what had datetime data. 2 of the 3 columns were hidden so I decided not to format those. After formating those two columns, the save works.

```
columns.Command(commands =>
                  {
                      commands.Edit().Text("<span></span>").UpdateText("<span></span>").CancelText("<span></span>").HtmlAttributes(KendoHelper.EditHtmlAttributesFor(Model));
                  }).Width(Constants.DEFAULT_GRID_COLUMN_WIDTH_NARROWER).HeaderTemplate("<span class='k-icon k-i-warning'>").Visible(Model.CanUpdate || Model.CanDelete);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.MunkatarsLogId).Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.MunkatarsId).Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Datum).Format("{0:yyyy.MM.dd.}").EditorTemplateName("Date");
                  columns.Bound(c => c.MunkatarsEsemenyTipus.Nev).EditorTemplateName("MunkatarsEsemenyTipus").EditorViewData(new { Kod = "#=MunkatarsEsemenyTipus.Kod#", Nev = "#=MunkatarsEsemenyTipus.Nev#" });
                  columns.Bound(c => c.EsemenyLeiras);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.BejegyzoMunkatarsId).Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.BejegyzesIdeje).Format("{0:yyyy.MM.dd.}").EditorTemplateName("Date").Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.UtolsoModositoId).Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.UtolsoModositasIdeje).Format("{0:yyyy.MM.dd.}").EditorTemplateName("Date").Hidden(true);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.Version).Hidden(true);
```